# usage of rsync without typing password

Tags: ssh, rsync

I'm working on a file download project which would download files from remote server to local server. The plan is to use rsync. when I perform rsync, it asks for my password on the remote server before starting the transfer. I would like to avoid this, and perform rsync without password.

I’ve googled a solution. Please see the link: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/rsync-over-ssh-without-password/

Let me give a brief introduction of this solution. The solution askes the user (like me) to use ssh-keygen on local server to generate public and private keys,
and then upload this public key to the remote server using ssh-copy-id. 
Since we need to download files from other companies’ servers, I'm kind of worried that other companies may not allow us to upload file to their servers.

Are there any other ways to avoid this password typing step?

Comment: If you can log in to the remote server(s) and create a directory called `.ssh` then you should be able to use key authentication.

Comment: @JRD, thanks so much for your reply. Can you give me a little bit introduction about using key authentication?

Comment: [SSH Keys](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) is an good overview. In a nutshell, you place a string value in a file on the remote server, and when you attempt to login, it looks for this string value and if it can be found you are allowed in. Very similar to a doorman at an apartment, once your info is on file at the desk and the doorman recognizes you, you do not have to provide id to enter.